# In sympy, how functional expression can be translated into operator overloaded expression?

Tags: python, expression, sympy, prefix, infix-notation

Recently I am working with boolean network and I am using sympy to manipulate boolean functions. I think this can be very basic question but I could not find any clue.

Following line works well.

```
>>>from sympy import *
>>>x,y = symbols("x y")
>>>(x | y) & x
And(Or(x, y), x)
```

Here I have very simple question. How the expression 'And(Or(x, y), x)' can be expressed as '(x | y) & x'?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sympy makes extensive use of Python operator overloading capabilities.
In Python each class can define as any mathematical operator will take effect, by defining methods with special names - these methods allways are prefixed and postfixed  with `__`, and are described in the [Python Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html).

Sympy symbols and expressions are objects that redefine all of the operator-related methods to perform an operation that return a Sympy expression object instead of a numeric result.

Thus, the operators for  bynary and `&` an dbinary or `|` are just one part of what Sympy does, and the long English versions `And` and `Or` function calls are provided as well for ease of typing and readability in certain contexts.

Comment: Thanks for kind detailed reply. Is there any simple function to translate string variable 'And(Or(x, y), x)' into string variable '(x | y) & x'? If the solution is not simple, then can you give some hint for doing that?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want nicer printing, you can run

```
init_printing()
```

and it will print it using Unicode characters, or even LaTeX if it's available (like in the Jupyter notebook)

```
In [1]: (x | y) & x
Out[1]: x ∧ (x ∨ y)
```

You can also use the `pprint()` function to get this directly.

It looks like the default SymPy printers use `And` and `Or` instead of the `&` and `|` symbols to print logic expressions, so if you explicitly want those, you would need to subclass `sympy.printing.str.StrPrinter` and override `_print_And` and `_print_Or` (see the [current implementation](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/17d046e8386fb4098d442b04f4b7bcf8a798f5b9/sympy/printing/str.py#L77) to get an idea of how that would work).

Comment: I've opened an issue to change the default printing in SymPy https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/11435

Comment: I found it a good solution for my problem. Thanks for the good hint.